# Missing Controller Exception after installing FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I installed `FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview` using

```
php ../composer.phar require friendsofcake/cakephp-csvview:~3.0.
```

After which all pages show **Missing Controller Exception** (they were definitely OK), even after commenting out `Plugin::load('CsvView')` in `bootstrap.php`. I doubt php was unable to locate the controller class but don't know why.  I have used `find . -mtime -1`, no files under `src` have changed.

Could anyone please tell me how Cakephp figures out the class file locations so I can troubleshoot?

Stack trace below:

```
2016-10-04 03:20:39 Warning: Headers already sent in {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/Debugger.php:753
2016-10-04 03:20:39 Error: [Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException] Controller class Holders could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'Holders',
  'plugin' => false,
  'prefix' => false,
  '_ext' => false,
)
Request URL: /
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Stack Trace:
#0 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ControllerFactory.php(72): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->missingController(Object(Cake\Network\Request))
#1 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Filter/ControllerFactoryFilter.php(63): Cake\Http\ControllerFactory->create(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#2 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Filter/ControllerFactoryFilter.php(49): Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter->_getController(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#3 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/DispatcherFilter.php(144): Cake\Routing\Filter\ControllerFactoryFilter->beforeDispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#4 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(426): Cake\Routing\DispatcherFilter->handle(Object(Cake\Event\Event), Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#5 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php(391): Cake\Event\EventManager->_callListener(Array, Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#6 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventDispatcherTrait.php(78): Cake\Event\EventManager->dispatch(Object(Cake\Event\Event))
#7 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/ActionDispatcher.php(81): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatchEvent('Dispatcher.befo...', Array)
#8 {base}/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(60): Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#9 {base}/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Just uninstall the plugin and check if it's working or not. Use this `composer remove FriendsOfCake/cakephp-csvview` then `composer update`

Comment: That does not help.  But I do composer self-update, create-app again and moved back my source code.  It works now.

Comment: My question "Could anyone please tell me how Cakephp figures out the class file locations so I can troubleshoot?" is still valid, and I'll be glad to accept an answer to that.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post the _complete_ error message including the _full_ stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP. The context information that is available for every error when debug mode is enabled, can also be very helpful, as it shows what data is involved.

Answer (score 0):

If at all, CakePHP only tries to figure fully qualified classnames from shorter ones, it doesn't handle including class files or figuring their locations, as of CakePHP 3 it relies on the [**composer autoloader**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) (`vendor/autoload.php`) to do that.

If things broke after updating a dependency, which will also cause the autoloader to be re-dumped, chances are good that the autoloader broke (for whatever reason).